# Whats the neatest logic to convert a bool into a text value

Tags: c#, php, boolean

I find myself writing code very similar to this regularly, in PHP and in C#

```
print isset($required) ? ($required ? "required" : "not required") : "not required";
```

Feels like I should be able to do something like this

```
print falseornull($required) ? "not required" : "required"
```

I could write a function to do this for me in PHP or C#, but I'm wondering if something already exists in either language? In C# I know there's `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check for blank strings. Any equivalents for other types?

Comment: What about better way in PHP? `print (isset($required) && $required) ? "required" : "not required");`

Comment: the type bool can hold only True or False values and cannot hold a null value in c# (unless declared as bool? which is a seperate type)

Comment: actually those are pretty neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a code simplifier...  If you're not checking for $required to be equal to a particular value, this:

```
print isset($required) ? ($required ? "required" : "not required") : "not required";
```

should be the same as this:

```
print empty($required) ? "not required" : "required";
```

empty() does just what you're after:  "Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it **does not exist or if its value equals FALSE**. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist. [...] The following things are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)"

https://www.php.net/empty

Comment: yeah empty seems to be what I'm after. shame there isn't something in c# that does the same for multiple types.

Comment: Why reverse empty()??  You may as well use isset()

Comment: @Coulton Fair enough.  Updated to flip flop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the equivalent to C#'s `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is `empty()` in PHP.  If the value is not set (NULL) or is set to false it will return `true`

```
// We'll set some variables in PHP
$variable1 = null;
$variable2 = 0;
$variable3 = false;

// Variable that doesn't exist, because we've commented it out
// $variable4 = 'something';

// When put into the function like so
print empty($variable1) ? true : false; // true
print empty($variable2) ? true : false; // false
print empty($variable3) ? true : false; // true
print empty($variable4) ? true : false; // true
```

Here's the docs for the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

`isset()` is the opposite function

Comment: that looks useful alright. Does it work for other types? string / int etc?

Comment: Yes, PHP isn't strongly typed like C#

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a `C#` alternative:

```
bool? b = .... ;
Console.WriteLine(b.GetValueOrDefault(false) ? "istrue" : "isnottrue");
```

Disclaimer, writing this without `C#` compiler at hand, but it should be `GetValueOrDefault` :)